# ng-repeat running multiple times in one go?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I got this quite simple

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="c in schedIdTableCtrl.calculateNumberOfColumns() track by $index">{{schedIdTableCtrl.calculateTime($index)}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And it returns an array with 504 elements.

But when I `console.log()` it says

```
(2) 504
(2) 504
504
```

So instead of running only once, it is running five times?

My javascript for this is simply

```
ctrl.calculateNumberOfColumns = () => {
    let columns = length / interval;
    console.log(columns);
    return new Array(columns);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a normal behaviour, related to the Angular `$digest` cycle.

> This cycle can be considered as a loop, during which Angular checks if
>   there are any changes to all the variables watched by all the scopes.
>   So if you have `$scope.myVar` defined in your controller and this
>   variable was marked for being watched, then you are explicitly telling
>   Angular to monitor the changes on `myVar` in each iteration of the loop. [*Source*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/how-do-i-use-scope-watch-and-scope-apply-in-angularjs/15113029#15113029)

If it possible to bind variable one time only in Angular, using `::`. See [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187670/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-angular/43187726#43187726).